# Plotting 3D Surface Graph

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, visualization, data-analysis

I'm facing an issue while trying to generate a 3D surface plot in MATLAB using the surf function. The error message I'm encountering is "Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector."

The MATLAB script involves loading data from a MAT file. Within this MAT file is a list of 1x2000 designs, all of them have a specific list of data for themselves.

In 3D surface plots, each point (X, Y) corresponds to a height determined by the value of Z, but besides a 3D scatter plot, are there any things that I can do to plot a 3D surface graph?

Any insights or suggestions for this issue would be highly appreciated.

I've tried using meshgrid on the X and Y vectors and then attributed the Z value using griddata and then surf but I'm not getting anything out of it.

Here's the code for referencing.

```
% Load data from MAT files
dataStruct = load('optimised.mat'); 
ValDesign = dataStruct.valid;  % Get inside the structure

% Number of valid design
[Num_row, Num_col] = size(ValDesign);

% Initialize matrix to store value
MassLoad_1 = zeros(1,Num_col);
MassLoad_2 = zeros(1,Num_col);
TotalMass = zeros(1,Num_col);

% Extract data from each aircraft
for i=1:Num_row
    for j=1:Num_col

        currentAircraft = ValDesign(i, j);
        MassLoop(j) = currentAircraft.mass; % Extract the desired variables

        % Get inside the structure
        PayLoadStruct(j) = ValDesign(i,j).payload;
        mis2_data(j) = PayLoadStruct(j).mass2; % Extract the desired variables
        mis3_data(j) = PayLoadStruct(j).mass3; % Extract the desired variables

        % Store values into a matrix
        MassLoad_1(i,j)= mis2_data(j);
        MassLoad_2(i,j)= mis3_data(j);
        TotalMass(i,j)= MassLoop(j);

    end
end

[MassLoad1_grid, MassLoad2_grid]= meshgrid(MassLoad_1,MassLoad_2);
surf(MassLoad1_grid,MassLoad2_grid,TotalMass);
```

Picture 1 is the structure of the MAT files, it contains a list of 1x2000 designs. Picture 2 is inside one of the designs, and I try to plot to total mass with two other masses inside the payload.

Here are some images from my MAT files

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Rf1.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZTV2.png)

Comment: We don't have access to your mat file, can you [edit] your question to generate some dummy data which represents your actual data so we can run your code? This would make it a [mcve]

Comment: thanks for the advice, i just added some picture from my mat file

Comment: A picture of a mat file is not something we can use to run your code, please read how to create a [mcve], you could use `rand()` or something else to create dummy variables which represent the ones required to run your code, without needing the mat file

Comment: either upload `.mat` file or something similar for the problem to be reproducible

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using `griddata` to interpolate 2-D or 3-D scattered data.
For example, assuming your points are `x,y,z`

```
xrange=linspace(min(x),max(x));
yrange=linspace(min(y),max(y));

[xq,yq] = meshgrid(xrange, yrange);
zq = griddata(x,y,z,xq,yq);

 mesh(xq,yq,zq)
 hold on
 plot3(x,y,z,"o")
```